# Помогите, пожалуйста, с расстановкой знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Для меня это нечто большее — надежда на лучшее ну и конечно же новая возможность воплощать в жизнь то, о чем я так давно мечтала.*

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить знаки препинания в этом предложении. Возникают сложности с "ну и конечно же".

Answer (score 1):

*Для меня это нечто большее — надежда на лучшее, **ну и,  конечно же,** новая возможность воплощать в жизнь то, о чем я так давно мечтала.*

Ответ Грамоты.ру:

> Вопрос № 298998
>
> Следует ли обособлять слово "конечно же" в предложении "Ну и конечно
>   же желаю, чтобы деньги текли к вам рекой, любви было море, а счастья —
>   океан!"
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Нужно обособление: ***Ну и, конечно же, желаю..***.

В вашем предложении (в соответствии с его структурой) обособление желательно, тем более что это соответствует правилам. С другой стороны, это сочетание обособляется не всегда. В правилах Розенталя говорится о том, что при выражении уверенности возможно отсутствие запятой (Правда? — Конечно правда!). Розенталь (п. 9.4.) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Пример из Нацкорпуса: **Ну и конечно же взять** ответственность на самих себя.  [А. Алексеев. Падение монархии в России: заговоры и революция // «Наука и жизнь», 2007]